# Why my random DateTime generator make dates outside of range?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

I have a function to generate random DateTime in range between two dates... and somehow it makes random dates that comes before minimal date. What's wrong with my code?

```
public void TestFunct()
{
    GenerateRandomTimeBetweenDates(new Random(), DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.2017 00:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTime.ParseExact("01.02.2017 00:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

public DateTime GenerateRandomTimeBetweenDates(Random RNG, DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
{
    int dt1_sec = (int)dt1.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds; //calc seconds since Unix epoch
    int dt2_sec = (int)dt2.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
    int random_sec = RNG.Next(Math.Min(dt1_sec, dt2_sec), Math.Max(dt1_sec, dt2_sec)); //RNG is Random instance. Here I generate seconds amount between two amounts - minimal and maximal.

    DateTime random_dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(random_sec); //I try to recreate date by adding generated seconds amount to Unix epoch.

    if (random_dt.Year == 2016)
        random_dt = random_dt; //this I use to trigger breakpoint

    return random_dt;
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Dont forget to  check` if (dt1 > dt2)` ?
2) `DateTime random_dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(random_sec).AddSeconds(dt1_sec);`

Comment: What happens in your `BuyersManager.RNG.Next`?

Comment: @krillgar - sorry, forgot to point this is just normal Random instance.

Comment: Is the random value that you get back within a range that you're expecting?

Comment: @krillgar - Yes, I added screen. `random_sec` is exactly within a range. But when I recreate DateTime it becomes less than minimal date.

Comment: What is `dt1` and `dt2`, this is local or utc time? I think this is localtime. And when you call `ToUniversalTime` you get utc date in 2016 year. From your example 1483214400 is 2016-12-31T20:00:00+00:00.

Comment: @Dmitry - Oh, right, they are local time. So I need to cast `random_dt` to local time?

Comment: @Kosmos - Can you please provide a [mcve]? We need to be able to copy, paste and run your code to see what you're seeing.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I though you can copy function above and see. But right, this is bad example. I will remake it.

Comment: Depends on the result that you want to get. If local time is needed result, convert to localtime. Add `ToLocalTime()` to `random_dt`.

Comment: @Dmitry, got it, thanks. I will follow `Evk` advice and remove `ToUniversalTime` call.

Comment: @Kosmos - You need to provide the inputs a the code that leads to the output that you get. It doesn't matter how good the program is just as long as we can see the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `ToUniversalTime()`. If your dates have kind of `Local` or `Unspecified` - `ToUniversalTime` will convert them to UTC assuming (in case of `Unspecified`) that they are local. By doing that, your `dt1`, which is January 1, 2017 will be represented in UTC as a date in 2016 year. When random value is close to minimal value - result will also be in 2016 year. To fix - just remove call to `ToUniversalTime()`. You can just remove it, because, by documentation of `Substract` method:

> The System.DateTime.Subtract(System.DateTime) method does not
>   consider the value of the System.DateTime.Kind property of the two
>   System.DateTime values when performing the subtraction

Note however that it's better to return result with the same kind as inputs, so:

```
DateTime random_dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, dt1.Kind).AddSeconds(random_sec);
```

Because otherwise if your input represents local time and result is in UTC - doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you. I made as you told and no more outsiders for me.